# kivy small green lines in ListView in Vertical BoxLayout

Tags: python, kivy

How can I make normal size for green lines?

My code for Box Layout is looks good on PC and bad on Android.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: see screenshot, please]

Comment: Show us the code that is causing the issue (or at least what you think is causing the issue)

Answer (score 0):

You probably set your button's height in a different unit from your font_size, so while the font_size is addapted to the different dpi of the android screen, your button's height is not. If you used `dp` or `sp` for the text, use it for the height of the button too.